# bulk emails with excel

Tags: excel, for-loop, integer, vba

Trying to create a bulk email workbook out of Excel using VBA code which includes embedded images.  I'm unable to apply a "`For i`" to the code and can't figure out how to email from an entire list with a `ListObject table`.  For the script below, the Sheet referenced is "Message Generator."  I'm trying to send an individual email to everyone in the list until the value in the row in Column B = 0.  However, the Integer I set for the loop seems to return the value 0, as though there are no values in the rows and columns at all.

Anyone know how I can send create a workbook to send bulk emails?  See below for the script.  Thank you!

```
Dim MainWB As Workbook
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olemail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim ts As Scripting.TextStream
Dim SigPath As String, SigText As String
SigPath = Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\New.htm"
     Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
     Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(SigPath)
SigText = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
     Set fso = Nothing
     Set MainWB = ActiveWorkbook

Dim Subject As String
Dim Body As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim l As Integer
l = NumberOfNonBlankRowsInColumn(2) - 2 'subtract 2 header rows
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

For i = 0 To l
    Set olemail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    Subject = MainWB.Sheets("Message Generator").Range("B3").Offset(i, 0).Value
    Body = MainWB.Sheets("Message Generator").Range("AB3").Offset(i, 0).Value
    With olemail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .To = "UTOAI@outlook.com"
        .Subject = Subject
        .Body = Body
        .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\Jacka\Documents\Test\logo.jpg"
        .HTMLBody = "<img src='cid:logo.jpg'" & "width='309.5' height='39.5'><br>" & _vbanewline & .HTMLBody & SigText
        .Display
        End With
        Set olemail = Nothing
Next i 
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Function NumberOfNonBlankRowsInColumn(souceCol As Integer) As Integer

```
Dim NumberOfRowsInColumn As Integer, j As Integer
Dim CurrentRowValue As String
NumberOfRowsInColumn = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).row

For j = 1 To NumberOfRowsInColumn
    CurrentRowValue = Cells(j, sourceCol).Value

If IsEmpty(CurrentRowValue) Or CurrentRowValue = "" Then
Exit For
End If
Next j
NumberOfNonBlankRowsInColumn = (j - 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to make this mistake.  The reason it worked sometimes and not others is because I had a value in the row *above* my column which later deleted.  Therefore, I set NonBlankRowsInColumn to 2 (where the values begin) and done. See the edited function below.

---

Function NumberOfNonBlankRowsInColumn(souceCol As Integer) As Integer

```
Dim NumberOfRowsInColumn As Integer, j As Integer
Dim CurrentRowValue As String
NumberOfRowsInColumn = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).row

For j = 2 To NumberOfRowsInColumn
    CurrentRowValue = Cells(j, sourceCol).Value

If IsEmpty(CurrentRowValue) Or CurrentRowValue = "" Then
Exit For
End If
Next j
NumberOfNonBlankRowsInColumn = (j - 1)
End Function
```